# Converting audio data from RTMP Stream to PCM or WAV format in Python

Tags: python, wav, rtmp, pcm

We have an audio stream running on an RTMP server and we tried to use `librtmp` library in Python to read the stream. We used the following code to get the stream data-

```
import librtmp

# Create a connection
conn = librtmp.RTMP("rtmp://your.server.net/app/playpath", live=True)
# Attempt to connect
conn.connect()
# Get a file-like object to access to the stream
stream = conn.create_stream()
# Read 1024 bytes of data
data = stream.read(1024)
```

This is the result when I print `data`:

```
b'FLV\x01\x05\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x01M\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\nonMetaData\x03\x00\x08duration\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08filesize\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05width\x00@\x94\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06height\x00@\x86\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0cvideocodecid\x02\x00\x04avc1\x00\rvideodatarate\x00@i\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\tframerate\x00@>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0caudiocodecid\x02\x00\x04mp4a\x00\raudiodatarate\x00@`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0faudiosamplerate\x00@\xe7p\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0faudiosamplesize\x00@0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\raudiochannels\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06stereo\x00?\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07encoder\x02\x00\x1eRogue Amoeba RTMP Streamer 1.0\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x01X\x08\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xaf\x00\x11\x90\x00\x00\x00\x0f'
```

The `data` object contains encoded data with FLV tags and due to insufficient documentation , we have been unable to use `data` to convert to PCM format. So is there a way to do this? Or are there other libraries in Python to read rtmp stream  and convert to PCM format?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question, yet?

Comment: Nope, we ended up using ffmpeg to read rtmp stream and piping the packets to server.